# Initializing an array of objects with {" ", " "}

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize an array of String (the class contains a default constructor and a constructor like this one: `String(const char* helper)`. I also have overloaded operator for <<;
However when I try to do the following, nothing happens :

```
 String suits[4] = {"Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades"};
        std::cout << suits[2];
```

But this one is okay :

```
        const String suit = "Hearts";
        std::cout <<suit;
```

0

it works the same without the const. I wanted to build myself the string class. About the string class :

```
class String
{
    char* buffer;
    int size;
    public:

    String(const char* helper)
    {
        size_t sizeH = strlen(helper);
        buffer = new char[sizeH];
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeH; ++i)
        {
            buffer[i] = helper[i];
        }
        buffer[sizeH] = 0;
        size = sizeH;
    }
    String()
    {
        buffer = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }
    void sizeOfBuffer()
    {
        std::cout <<size<<"\n";
    }

    ~String()
    {
        delete[] buffer;
    }
```

Comment: What does the second example do without the `const`?

Comment: Does it work if you use std::string instead?  Please post the code of your String class.

Comment: @Daskal Botio Show a minimal complete program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `buffer[sizeH] = 0;` writes past the end of the allocated array - it invokes *undefined behavior*. You need to allocate `strlen(helper) + 1` for `buffer`

Comment: Hmm, I just saw the same class in another question. It **does** need the copy constructor.